# Javascript json diff patch html viewer doesn't match demo

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to follow the instructions for the jsondiffpatch javascript library, but I'm getting different results than are shown on their demo page.

Instructions:

https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch#visual-diff

Demo Page:
https://benjamine.github.io/jsondiffpatch/demo/index.html?

Demo Data Left:

```
{
  "key1": "value4",
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "Name": "Blue Shirt",
      "ProductId": 10
    },
    {
      "Name": "Red Mug",
      "ProductId": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Demo Data Right:

```
{
  "key1": "value4",
  "lineItems": [
    {
      "Name": "Blue Shirts",
      "ProductId": 10
    },
    {
      "Name": "Red Mug",
      "ProductId": 30
    }
  ]
}
```

My Code (called from Blazor):

```
    window.renderDiff = function (left, right, element) {
      var delta = jsondiffpatch.diff(left, right);
      element.innerHTML = jsondiffpatch.formatters.html.format(delta, left);
      jsondiffpatch.formatters.html.showUnchanged();
      return element.innerHTML;
    }
```

Their rendering on the demo looks like this:

[image]

Annotated:

[image]

But mine looks very different:

[image]

What Am I doing wrong? My code matches theirs almost exactly. I looked through the source code of the demo and could not find any settings being specified that would give it a different appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem as I was typing this up and thought I'd post the solution in case anyone has the same problem. I was sending my `left` and `right` as json strings, not objects the fix was to parse them to json objects first:

```
    window.renderDiff = function (left, right, element) {
      //parse to json object
      left = JSON.parse(left);
      right = JSON.parse(right);

      var delta = jsondiffpatch.diff(left, right);
      element.innerHTML = jsondiffpatch.formatters.html.format(delta, left);
      jsondiffpatch.formatters.html.showUnchanged();
      return element.innerHTML;
    }
```